# Using a Jim Miller Tenon Jig

Tags: workbench, vises

Has anybody built the tenon cutting jig from [this article](https://www.popularwoodworking.com/woodworking-blogs/chris-schwarz-blog/jeff-miller%E2%80%99s-incredible-tenon-jig) ([video here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PJcaha_aq8c)). I bought the issue of Popular Woodworking issue that it came from and it says the curved support (on the left in the picture) is optional and I'd like to try to build one without it.  But I can't figure out how the jig would be held to the bench.  I need to get a suitable vise and can't get a fancy tail vise as used in the picture.  Would a Moxon-style vise work?

Comment: A twin-screw vice is an option for holding this in place, but what's used in the pic isn't a fancy tail vice, it's a standard woodworking vice, it just has a wide wooden lining attached to the front jaw.